# Error: Could not find activemodel-3.2.13 in any of source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with launching of the ready project.
When i launch the program with:

> rails s
>   I get:
>   Could not find activemodel-3.2.13 in any of sources
>
> Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems

After running:

> bundle install

I have:

> Installing mysql2 0.3.16 with native extensions
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> e:/Different/RoR/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
>
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> Gem files will remain installed in e:/Different/RoR/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
>
> Results logged to e:/Different/RoR/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling.

Thats not all log, just with errors.

So next i run:

> gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'

I get:

> ERROR: Error installing mysql2:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
>
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Gem files will remain installed in E:/Different/RoR/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
>
> Results logged to E:/Different/RoR/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

So what should i do?
Earlier I have one more error connected with  SSL connection error. So I couldnt load from http://rubygems.org/. But it seems like its gone now.

My GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'rake', '10.2.1'
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'annotate', '>=2.6.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem "date-input-rails"
gem "nested_form"
gem 'debugger'
#gem "thin"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

My GemFile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    annotate (2.6.1)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    arel (3.0.3)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.3.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.0.0.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    date-input-rails (0.0.3)
      jquery-ui-rails
      rails (~> 3.2.8)
    debugger (1.6.8)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.5)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.7)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    haml (4.0.5)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      haml (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    multi_json (1.8.4)
    mysql2 (0.3.16)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.2.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.14)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.4.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  annotate (>= 2.6.0)
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.0.1)
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  date-input-rails
  debugger
  haml-rails
  jquery-rails
  mysql2
  nested_form
  rails (= 3.2.13)
  rake (= 10.2.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: Rails version: 4.2.5
Ruby version: 2.2.3-p173 (i386-mingw32) System: Windows 10

Comment: Up. actually can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guideline https://medium.com/@frontlineutils/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3#.op5rwsf2e

As I'm no more on windows, I can't test it again, but it should still work.

Comment: What the output when you do `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby  --with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector-path"` ?
With the right mysql-connector-path

Comment: OK,
Have you downloaded zip archive of mysql-connector from here : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Let's suppose you have unzipped *mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32* at the root of *e:*
The command to run will be: 
`gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby --with-mysql-dir="e:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32"`

Comment: And with : `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="e:/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32"'`
(slash instead of backslash)
Otherwise, i really don't know what happens. It has worked for me

Comment: hey, just recognized. Where can i find this dll? i took it from mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32/lib. But where is this bin folder? Cause mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32/bin doesnt contain libmysql.dll. So where is mysql_files/bin?

Comment: I think the post's author just mistyped folder's name. To me the dll is under */lib* folder.

What  do you get now, when you perform a `bundle install`

Comment: Same result. R u sure about folder? Cause i just download new archive with mysql and in folder lib there is already libmysql.dll by default. So we dont need to do gem install mysql2 etc? Maybe its another folder?

Comment: For me you have to pick *libmysql.dll* from `mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32/lib` and place it under your `ruby/bin` folder. And for sure you have to install mysql2 gem. What's the output of `bundle install`?

Comment: Too big log, so 3 pics: 1) http://postimg.org/image/s2lpufgh7/ 2) http://postimg.org/image/d3vo4hegt/ 3) http://postimg.org/image/5232if9nt/

Comment: Seems mysql2 gem wasn't installed when you performed : `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="e:/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32"'`

Comment: So what should i do? I dont understand, maybe reason is not in mysql2? On the internet I saw that this (activemodel) can be a problem that connected with versions of ruby. But couldnt find how to fix it :(